# Blur differences between camera move vs object move?

Tags: motion-blur

I'm planning for a larger animation.
And in this animation there will be a lot of camera travel.
Now I wonder what's best. Should I move the static scene and the objects or the camera? Does it differ for motion blur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If handled properly, moving the objects in the scene will produce exactly the same motion blur as moving the camera.

However, it requires that you move objects at rates that depend on how far they are from the camera, so as to preserver parallax.

If you have one object moving in a more or less straight path, more or less parallel to the focal plane, you can get away with this fairly easily -- It's a technique that animators have used since the early days of Cel based animation.

The more objects you have to move, the more you have to adjust.